# My discord ui buttons always throw 'This Interaction Failed'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

Creating my first Discord bot and I'm running into an issue with the buttons and interactions.
No matter what I do I only get an error which says 'This Interaction Failed'

The bot has tested perms to add roles, assign roles, delete roles, create/delete channels and send + read user messages. I saw a reddit post about doing something like this to fix the error

```
async def on_button_click(interaction):
    your code
    try:
        interaction.respond()
    except:
        pass
```

but I can't figure out how to implement this or if I'm already doing this. I know it has to do with callbacks lol.

Here is the code. If more information is needed please let me know. I'm not sure how to log as well because my google cloud vm throws no errors.

buttons and view come from here

`from discord.ui import Button, View`

```
@bot.command()
async def invite(ctx, user: discord.User):
    if ctx.author.id not in clan_data:
        await ctx.send("You are not in any clan. Create a clan first.")
        return

    # Check if the author of the message is the clan creator
    clan_creator_id = ctx.author.id
    if clan_creator_id not in clan_data:
        await ctx.send("Only the clan creator can invite users.")
        return

    clan_name, channel_id, role_id, member_list= clan_data[clan_creator_id]
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=f"Invitation to {clan_name}",
        description=f"You have been invited to {clan_name} by {ctx.author.name}",
        color=discord.Color.blurple()
    )
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon.url)

    accept_button = Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, label="Accept", custom_id="join")
    reject_button = Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.red, label="Reject", custom_id="reject")

    action_row = View()
    action_row.add_item(accept_button)
    action_row.add_item(reject_button)

    await user.send(embed=embed, view=action_row)
```

```
@bot.event
async def on_component(interaction):
    if interaction.custom_id == "join":
        await interaction.response.send_message("Accepted.", ephemeral=True)
        await handle_accept(interaction)
    elif interaction.custom_id == "reject":
        await interaction.response.send_message("Invite rejected.", ephemeral=True)
    

async def handle_accept(interaction):
    user = interaction.user
    guild = bot.get_guild(1159153096191123517) #REPLACE WITH YOUR SERVER ID
    clan_creator_id = None
    for key, value in clan_data.items():
        if value[2] == interaction.message.embeds[0].title:
            clan_creator_id = key
            break
    if clan_creator_id is not None:
        role_id = clan_data[clan_creator_id][2]
        role = guild.get_role(role_id)
        if role is not None:
            clan_data[clan_creator_id][3].append(user.id)
            await user.add_roles(role)
            await interaction.response.send_message("You have accepted the invitation.", ephemeral=True)
        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message("Role not found!", ephemeral=True)
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message("Invalid Invitation!", ephemeral=True)
```

Main thing I have tried is this:

```
async def on_button_click(interaction):
    your code
    try:
        interaction.respond()
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: @Jordan is that not literally the point of stack overflow, to figure out other peoples issues??? Also other problems I've solved threw errors but this one does not so no logs.

Comment: @Jordan You have no point here. If you wouldn't like to help, then don't. It is that simple...

Comment: @caiomauro No worries! :D

Comment: @rexy we want to solve issues, not find them. I personally think that it's a waste of time to have to manually read all your code to find where the issue is occuring. Narrow it down, and then ask for help.

Comment: @Jordan As I said earlier it is fine. If you don't want to help in this case, then don't. But let others help who are willing to find problems. And it isn't even the main reason of his question, he just mentioned it if we know why it occurs.  So please if you don't want to help, just move on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code for a simple button interaction:

```
class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Test",style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="my_custom_button")
    async def testbutton(self,interaction:discord.Interaction,button:discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_message("Testing...")

@bot.tree.command(name='testbutton')
async def testbutton(interaction:discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(view=MyView())
```

Explanation:
(*You can put the code in the main file it is not a cog.*)

You create a class for the button. Inside that class you directly respond to the button click by mentioning the button itself. With the command you only send the button.

For this button to work after the bot restarts in your **on_ready** event add this line: `bot.add_view(MyView())`
Of course if you rename the class rename the **MyView** part inside the line.

Comment: This did help me solve the problem and actually understand how the buttons work, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! If you are interested in further help you can message me in discord (@rexy.py).